# React props are being evaluated even if the component is still suppose to be rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a wrapper for my components that tells them not to render until they are done loading that looks like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import LoadingSpinner from 'vivid.react.components/atoms/LoadingSpinner';

class Wrapper extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getInitialState();
    }

    render() {
        const { error, isLoadingInitialState } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className='wrapper'>
                {!!error && <div>Error: {error.message}</div>}
                {isLoadingInitialState
                    ? <LoadingSpinner/>
                    :  children
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default Wrapper;
```

However, when I used this wrapper inside a Context Consumer, the props of the children are still being evaluated even if the LoadingInitialState is true and the children is not supposed to render.

```js
const Screen = () => {
    <div>
     <Context.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
          <Wrapper isLoadingInitialState={context.isLoadingInitialState} getInitialState={context.getInitialState)>
            <ChildComponent price = {context.data.props}/> // throws an error because data is undefined
          </Wrapper>
      }}
    </Context.Context>
}
```

Can anyone explain why the ChildComponents props are still being evaulated even thought its not being rendered? Is there a better solution to do this?

Comment: Is this the complete code of `Wrapper`? What is the initial value of `isLoadingInitialState` ?

Comment: I suppose that initial value of isLoadingInitialState equals undefined.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the code. The initial value of isLoadingInitialState is set as true in the parent of Screen and passed down through the context. The issue is that the value of the props of ChildComponent are being evaluated before the render method of Wrapper and i have no idea why

Comment: @ Yucheng Lin is there a better solution to do this - you can try with HigherOrderComponent. check it out https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/handle-loadings-in-react-by-using-higher-order-components-2ee8de9c3deb

Comment: @AravindS I will take a look at that article. Do you know why this doesnt work though?

Comment: @YuchengLin i am not sure..may the way based the props to children may wrong.